# Mock of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger is null after instantiation

Tags: c#, .net, mocking

I'm trying to mock `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` but it ends up being null in the `[TestInitialise]` method below. How come it is null?

```
public class MockLogger : ILogger
{
    // Define a public property for the message. 
    // Your unit tests can query this property
    // to validate that the method was called. 

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void LogToOperations(string message)
    {
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class DataServiceTests
{


    private ILogger<DataService> _logger;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        _logger = new MockLogger() as ILogger<DataService>;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logger does not implement generic `ILogger<T>` interface. That's why `as` operator returns `null` when conversion between `MockLogger` and `ILogger<DataService>` is not possible.

NOTE: Usually mocking types which you don't own considered as a [bad practice](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests). And one more thing - your `MockLogger` class is not mock - it's a [Dummy](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/14/TheLittleMocker.html). For mocking I would suggest you some existing library. E.g. [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) or [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart). With NSubstitute:

```
_logger = Substitute.For<ILogger<DataService>>;
```

without any additional code.

Comment: Yep. Accepting answer when allowed to. Thanks!

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins thanks, I have added some notes to answer, which might be helpful for you